# What happens if more than one user control registers $(document).ready function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a couple of user controls in an aspx page. And each user control may need to register a start-up block as an `$(document).ready()` function event handler.

Do they override each previous functions of they are chained in order of registration?

Comment: no unless they are operating on same element, you should get the result as you expected

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are just added as event handlers to the documents 'ready' event (an abstracted event provided by JQuery).

In JQuery event handlers are executed in the order they were bound.

Eventhandlers are not chained - as that would mean `handler#3` would not fire if `handler#2` failed to execute successfully. They are simply executed by the event manager in turn.

Answer (score 2):

They will all be run in the order they were registered. See the fifth paragraph in the documentation to [`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), which `.ready()`, `.load()` etc. are shortcuts of.

> When an event reaches an element, all handlers bound to that event type for the element are fired. If there are multiple handlers registered, they will always execute in the order in which they were bound. After all handlers have executed, the event continues along the normal event propagation path.

Comment: Pekka, Sean Kinsey writes: "Eventhandlers are not chained" in his answer. Is it against your argument or you basically say the same thing by using different definitions?

Comment: @PencilCake what @Sean is saying is that all handlers will run, even if one of them returns `false`. His definition is more correct, I'll fix my wording.

Answer (score 1):

jquery ready events can be registered multiple times and they are chained

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK they're chained in the order they are registered.